# Removal of Refresh Tokens

Tags: adal

I've posted this comment twice on Vittorio's blog about this here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbertocci/archive/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed.aspx, but it never shows up in the comments so I'm adding it here.

We have one specific scenario where we use RT that are in the context of a Windows service where there isn't an interactive user, the session information can start and stop unexpectedly, and it isn't feasible to develop a distributable custom ADAL caching mechanism.  RT are the logical choice, which seems to be the type of scenario you see described in the other comments here.  ADAL doesn't address this well today, RT do, and I haven't seen any business justification for removing them - only for keeping them.  Removing RT would adversely impact about 100+ of our customers using this solution.  If you have another workable solution in ADAL we're happy to use it, but if not then removing RT for some kind of protocol purist reason will be a big problem.

Answer (score 0):

The blog you are using is just a forwarder, as the posts of the last ~2 years should make clear. The actual posts are on www.cloudidentity.com.
The RTs aren't being removed for any "protocol purist reason", especially because *absolutely nothing* changes from the protocol perspective - it's just a matter of whether the library uses the RTs transparently, or your code does. The post you linked to provides concrete usability and functional reasons that led to that decision.
I don't understand the concern you are raising. Whatever mechanism you are using today for sharing and/or persisting the RTs, you can use for doing the exact same with the cache - it can be as simple as a flat file for each service, no need to do anything distributed if that makes you nervous. Furthermore, the topology you describe does not strictly rely on refresh tokens - if you are modeling your client as a confidential client, that means that you have credentials that can be exchanged for an access token at any time, while refresh token are meant as a mechanism for not prompting the user all the time while retaining the ability of revoking them. The client credentials would follow a completely different revocation path, hence one has to wonder why are you even worrying about refresh tokens in the first place.
Finally: this change is happening in ADAL v3. Nothing prevents you from staying on ADAL v2, that's why we use major versions when we introduce breaking changes.

Comment: I'm happy to talk about the specifics offline (as I put in my original comments on the blog post), but there are security concerns in a multi-customer distributed environment where it would not make sense to model the app as a confidential client.  There are a couple of flavors of this type of scenario that do not seem to get taken seriously by the ADAL team.  The result is we are having to work around these limitations as best we can, such as with RT and other methods.  The rationale described in the blog post is absent any business-related motives, which is why it lacks plausibility.

Comment: If you would mention the scenarios you are interested, without sharing any sensitive details, that would help. 
ADAL is mostly a projection of what the Azure AD service offers, lack of support for some scenarios in the library is by design if those aren't supported by AAD. I am not sure what you mean for "business-related motives". The presence of RTs prompted some developers do something dangerous in their code: absent this being a blocking factor for scenarios *supported* by Azure AD, the removal makes sense. It already prompted many people to discover and eliminate issues in their apps.

Comment: It's more than I can fit in the 600 or so characters permitted in the comments section, but if you email me at support@office365mon.com I will describe the two specific challenges that we find difficult to manage with ADAL.

Comment: I've offered multiple times now to explain via email and not heard back so I'll simply say this - generally there are gaps where trying to fit AAD into scenarios common in AD, such as the one I describe above. As AAD adoption increases, scenario such as that increases and it's rather silly to have everyone write their own ADAL cache for that.  Secondarily, scenarios involving service aggregation and provisioning have big gaps in ADAL. Finally, the assertion that some may do something "dangerous" with an API as a reason to remove it is illogical. Based on that almost all APIs would be removed.

Comment: Steve, as mentioned in the first reply - you can easily contact me on www.cloudidentity.com. All the statements in your latest comments are value judgements/ statements of opinions that are hard to discuss without concrete scenarios. I am happy to review any concrete scenario you want to discuss.